# Is this K-map grouping legal?

Tags: karnaugh-map

Can the following K-map be grouped with 1s in the corners of a subsection of a 16-cell K-map?

[image]

Comment: You need to group all the ones, or for inverted logic, all the zeros.

Comment: You are probably drawing boxes in a confusing way. [Here's](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D03Jq.png) an example that shows how you can circle 1's into a group that lies across a top-bottom edge, for example. The way you've drawn your boxes, it appears that you are including 1's and 0's in them. And you don't do that. Only 1's may reside in a grouping. In your case, you should have three: one group of four, another group of four that overlaps the first one, and a group of two. So three terms, total. It can be simplified (in some sense) by using one XOR and one OR gate.

Comment: If you respond, I may even add an answer for you. But you need to interact for that to happen.

Comment: It's illegal, I will call the police!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, K-maps wrap around like this. Moving from the top row to the bottom row is still only changing one bit.

The ones in the corners of your left rectangle are:

$$\overline{WXY}Z + \overline{WX}YZ + W\overline{XY}Z + W\overline{X}YZ$$

You can factor out the \$\overline X\$ and the \$Z\$:

$$\overline{X}Z(\overline{WY} + \overline{W}Y + W\overline{Y} + WY)$$

As you can see, the values in the parentheses cover all possible combinations of \$W\$ and \$Y\$, so they reduce to 1:

$$\overline{X}Z(1) = \overline{X}Z$$